# bulk versus single insert in OrientDB

Tags: etl, orientdb

I am new to OrientDB and couldn't find any explanation of why using oetl.sh would be much faster than say using the python api. I have an poorly formatted xml that i need to parse and store as a orientdb graph. Can someone explain the benefits of parsing the xml file, storing it as a .json object and using oetl.sh vs parsing the xml file and doing many inserts from python? Thanks in advance!